# How to popup AlertView on successful check of pin in ObjC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10

I am trying to create a small app in which user need to enter the pin on the correct pin it will say correct pin else wrong but I am not sure if my logic is correct below. I am using the `Xcode10` on the latest `Mac` version.

```
- (IBAction)validatePin:(id)sender {
[ViewController checkPin:self.textPin.text.integerValue];
}

+(BOOL)checkPin:(NSInteger)pin {
if (pin == 1408)
{
   //[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Pin" message:@"Success" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Title"
                               message:@"are you sure?"
                              delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                     otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    return YES;
}
[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Pin" message:@"Fail" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
return NO;}
```

I have tried both the `UIAlertView` and `UIAlertController` method but I get no response to the app. Can someone correct this code in `ObjC`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create method, you can directly check and shoe an alert like this.

```
- (IBAction)validatePin:(id)sender {
    if (self.textPin.text.integerValue == 1408) {
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title"
                                                                   message:@"PIN is Correct"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title"
                                                                   message:@"PIN is WRONG"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

If you want to use your code then change it to this.

```
- (IBAction)validatePin:(id)sender {
    BOOL isValidPin = [ViewController checkPin:self.textPin.text.integerValue];

    if (isValidPin) {
        // SHOW RIGHT ALERT
    }
    else {
        // SHOW WRONG ALERT
    }
}

+(BOOL)checkPin:(NSInteger)pin {
    if (pin == 1408) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2670674, Please accept this answer and when you have enough reputation please upvote it.